# How to set the color of an event to none using a patch request?

Tags: google-calendar-api

To set the color of an event of an event using the Google Calendar API, you need to change the `colorId` parameter of the event, which is a string valued `"1"` through `"11"`. Setting the body of a [patch request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch#try-it) to:

```
{
    "colorId" : "1"
}
```

for example, sets the color of the event to blue.

The default color of an event, however, is called "none" on Google Calendar. How can I set the color of an event back to "none" using a patch request?

Edit: After looking into the issue a little more, it seems like I need to remove the `colorId` property from the event altogether to set it to "none". How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you try using "null" or "0"?

Comment: I have tried "0", "null," and "none". None of them work.

Comment: I can confirm that when using Google App Script, `calendarEvent.setColor("0");` will remove the color, while `calendarEvent.setColor(null);` will produce an error.